# Open Office replace()

Tags: openoffice-basic

does Open Office BASIC support function replace(string,search string, replace with)?

Comment: with these tags no one will ever notice this question. Try to add other tags

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Open Office BASIC supports this function, but be aware it is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is `SUBSITUTE(input, search_text, replace_text[, occurrence])`

Examples:

```
input                                         | result
----------------------------------------------+-----------------
=SUBSTITUTE("nyan cat cat","cat","nyan!")     | nyan nyan! nyan!
=SUBSTITUTE("nyan cat cat","cat","nyan!", 1)  | nyan nyan! cat
=SUBSTITUTE("nyan cat cat","cat","nyan!", 2)  | nyan cat nyan!
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUBSTITUTE_function)

Answer (score -1):

Replaces part of a text string with a different text string.
Syntax:

```
REPLACE(originaltext; startposition; length; newtext)
```

> in originaltext, removes length characters beginning at character startposition, replaces them with newtext, and returns the result.
>
> startposition and length must be 1 or more.

Example:

```
REPLACE("mouse"; 2; 3; "ic")
```

> returns mice. Beginning at character position 2, 3 characters (ous) are removed and replaced by ic.